# Create json array of records with Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

I'm trying to create a json with multiple records by following this example: [Generate a sample JSON with an array in it in Delphi XE5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150164/generate-a-sample-json-with-an-array-in-it-in-delphi-xe5)
must be the same way, except that when I add the array to the object

```
JSonObj.AddPair (TJSONPair.Create ('records', TJSONArray));
```

returns the error:

> "There is the overloaded version of 'Create' that can be called with arguments These"

How do I add to the array object?
If I convert an array to string and add, to receive the amounts can not treat as an array ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing it the *class reference* for a JSON array. You need to pass it an *instance*.

```
arr := TJSONArray.Create;
JSONObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('records', arr));
```

Look carefully at the answers in the question you link to, and you'll see this is exactly what they're doing, too.